# Android hint problems xml

Tags: android, xml

I added an android:hint="utilizador" but when i run and when i test the application the label drops. and it should be in the textbox

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#40413E"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<!-- Login progress -->

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="126dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ipleiria_logo_pequena_v2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Inicie sessão com a sua conta institucional" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="71dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFFF"
                android:hint="Utilizador"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#FFFF"
                android:hint="Palavra-passe"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#EC0044"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="Iniciar Sessão"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="www.ipleiria.pt | Precisa de ajuda?"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

Comment: Can you add the layout xml?

Comment: @Kai pastebin.com/ysbRCL1h

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Utilizador" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AutoCompleteTextView` is not allowed as a child of `TextInputLayout` because you can't get working functionality or design of `AutoCompleteTextView`. Either take it out of `TextInputLayout` or replace `AutoCompleteTextView` with `TextInputEditText`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **TextInputLayout** with below one

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hints problem you can simple use this. This is actually alternative solution :

```
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="USERNAME"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```